# time data '2021-03-31 23:30:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S'

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

This simple example brings the error described above.

```
from datetime import datetime
obj = datetime.strptime('2021-03-31 23:30:00',  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S')
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You left out a '%' for seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a % at the seconds. Should be

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a % for the S-part

```py
from datetime import datetime
obj = datetime.strptime('2021-03-31 23:30:00',  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```